# ORACLE: USE RESULT OF CASE-WHEN-STATEMENT

Tags: sql, oracle, case-when

I have a huge query and I am wondering if it is in Oracle possible 
 to get the result of a case-when-statement and use it for comparison? My CASE-STATEMENT is declared in the Select-Statement and it looks like this.

```
SELECT........
  (CASE
     WHEN (Select 1 from DUAL) = 1 THEN 'TEST'
     ELSE 'TEST2'
  END) AS TEST;
```

Now I want to get the result of this case-statement and use it in the where part? Is it possible? (Sry this may be a dumb question)

Comment: The exact way you ask in your question is not possible. If you define the expression which you labeled (aliased) as `TEST` in the `SELECT` clause, the name `TEST` is not visible in the `WHERE` clause of the same `SELECT` query, because `WHERE` is processed before `SELECT`. If you don't want to repeat the same (possibly very long) `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause, you are better off defining `TEST` in a subquery, then select and use it in the `WHERE` clause in an outer query. (You can do that with a `WITH` clause.) Better for future code maintenance, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define your `CASE` statement in either an inline-view or a common table expression (aka `WITH` clause), you can refer to it by whatever alias you give it.

For example (inline-view):

```
SELECT ...
FROM   ( SELECT .....
         (CASE
             WHEN (Select 1 from DUAL) = 1 THEN 'TEST'
             ELSE 'TEST2'
          END) AS TEST
         FROM...
       ) v
WHERE  v.test = 'TEST2';
```

As a common table expression, it would be:

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT........
                (CASE
                   WHEN (Select 1 from DUAL) = 1 THEN 'TEST'
                   ELSE 'TEST2'
                END) AS TEST
              FROM ... )
SELECT ...
FROM   cte
WHERE  test = 'TEST2';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case` statement in the `where` clause, for eg.:

```
select * from table
where table.field = (CASE
                      WHEN (Select 1 from DUAL) = 1 THEN 'TEST'
                      ELSE 'TEST2'
                     END)
```

This will compare the value returned from the `case` statement with the table field.